# pfgplots tick label alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I am trying to generate economics graphs using pgfplots. The default for tick labels is to be centred. Is there any way that I can get a tick label to be aligned to the left or right?
My aim is to have the 160 aligned to the left, and the 200 aligned to the right so that I am able to fit another label in the middle.
Are there also perhaps ways to decrease the text size of the tick labels?

[image: My current source output]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scale = 1.2,
axis lines = middle,
xmin = 0, xmax = 650,
ymin = 0, ymax = 1300,
axis lines* = left,
xtick = {0,160,200,480,600}, ytick = {800,1200},
clip = false,
]

\node [right] at (current axis.right of origin) {X};
\node [above] at (current axis.above origin) {Y};

\addplot[domain = 0:600, samples = 1000, color= red]{-2*x+1200};

\addplot[domain = 50:350, restrict y to domain = 0:1150, samples = 1000, color= blue]{sqrt(128000000/(x))};

\filldraw[black] (200,800) circle (2pt) node[]{};
\draw[black, dashed] (200,0) -- (200,800);
\draw[black, dashed] (0,800) -- (200,800);

\addplot[domain = 0:480, samples = 1000, color= orange]{-2.5*x+1200};

\addplot[domain = 10:310, restrict y to domain = 0:1150, samples = 1000, color= green]{((8388608000000000000/(x^2))^(1/5))};

\filldraw[black] (160,800) circle (2pt) node[]{};
\draw[black, dashed] (160,0) -- (160,800);
\draw[black, dashed] (0,800) -- (160,800);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Would adding `xticklabels = {0,,,480,600}` to the axis options and defining two nodes as `\node[below left] at (160, 0) {160};` and `\node[below right] at (200, 0) {200};` do the trick for you?

Comment: For the font size of the tick labels, just add `ticklabel style = {font=\tiny}`, where `\tiny` is replaced by the font size you want, to your axis options. However, if you use the solution I provided in my last comment for the left and right aligned tick labels, you will have to add the font size in the label's content (e.g. `{\tiny 160}`).

Comment: @KersouMan these worked great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this (similar as mentioned in the @KersouMan comment, but a wee bit refined)?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, node contents={}},
lbl/.style = {inner xsep=0pt, below #1} 
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
scale = 1.2,
axis lines = middle,
xlabel=X,   xlabel style={anchor=west},
ylabel=Y,   ylabel style={anchor=south},
xmin = 0, xmax = 650,
ymin = 0, ymax = 1300, restrict y to domain = 0:1150,
xtick = {0,480,600}, ytick = {800,1200},
extra x ticks = {160,200}, extra x tick label=\empty,
clip=false,
            ]

\addplot[domain = 50:350, samples = 100, color= blue]   {sqrt(128000000/(x))};
\addplot[domain = 10:310, samples = 100, color= green]  {((8388608000000000000/(x^2))^(1/5))};

\draw[red] (0,1200) -- (600,0);
\draw[red] (0,1200) -- (480,0);

\draw[dashed] (160,0) node[lbl= left] {160} |- (0,800) node[pos=0.5, dot];
\draw[dashed] (200,0) node[lbl=right] {200} |- (0,800) node[pos=0.5, dot];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
between ticks at 160 and 200 you can insert `extra x ticks`, for example `extra x ticks = {180},` and its label rotate for 90 degrees.  MWE, which consider beforementioned is:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=2pt, node contents={}},
lbl/.style = {font=\footnotesize, inner xsep=0pt, 
              text=black, yshift=-0.5mm, below #1}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
scale = 1.2,
axis lines = middle,
xlabel=X,   xlabel style={anchor=west},
ylabel=Y,   ylabel style={anchor=south},
xmin = 0, xmax = 650,
ymin = 0, ymax = 1300, restrict y to domain = 0:1150,
xtick = {0,160,200,480,600}, xticklabels= {0, , ,480,600},
ytick = {800,1200},
xticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize},
extra x ticks = {180}, 
extra x tick style={tick label style={rotate=90, anchor=east}},
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick},
clip=false,
            ]
\addplot[domain = 50:350, samples = 100, color= blue]   {sqrt(128000000/(x))};
\addplot[domain = 10:310, samples = 100, color= green]  {(8388608000000000000/(x^2))^(1/5)};

\draw[red] (0,1200) -- (600,0);
\draw[red] (0,1200) -- (480,0);

\draw[densely dashed, very thin, gray]   
    (160,0) node[lbl= left] {160} |- (0,800) node[pos=0.5, dot]
    (200,0) node[lbl=right] {200} |- (0,800) node[pos=0.5, dot];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful to see how I could simplify my source especially with the straight lines.